# Why does my command work in IRB but not from a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, irb

The command below works in IRB but does not work from inside a Ruby program.

```
DISPLAY=:5 nohup firefox youtube.com &
```

In `irb` it successfully returns:

```
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
```

When called from a Ruby program within backticks ("`") it returns:

```
** (firefox:12402): WARNING **: Could not connect: Connection refused

** (firefox:12470): CRITICAL **: unable to create '/var/www/.cache/dconf'; dconf will not work properly.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":5".
Failed to stat home directory /var/www: No such file or directory

(firefox:12470): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-989cWYOeP6: Connection refused
```

Comment: Is the ruby script running as the same user?  Make sure you put `/usr/bin/env DISPLAY=:5 nohup ... ` as your command, in order to handle the environment variable correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response @d11wtq. I am receiving permission denied messages when I prefix with the code above

Comment: So when you're running the code in IRB, that is as the same user that the ruby script is running as?

Comment: That's a great question. The command (in the program) is being triggered by a web request. I am not sure how linux handles commands that are being triggered by a web request.

Comment: `www-data` is the user, I think. I ran a `whoami` command inside the ruby program.

Comment: Yeah, so completely different permissions.  The www-data user doesn't have permission to connect to the X session, or have an .Xauthority file configured.  Can you explain what you're trying to achieve, and then we can probably come up with a workaround.  Connecting to an Xserver via a web request seems kinda wonky and like it should be happening in a background task.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I am taking snapshots of webpages. The url is being passed to the command as a parameter. (Youtube.com would be the parameter passed in this case) I am willing to handle this another way if you have any ideas.

Comment: You can submit your answer regarding permissions whenever you're ready. That was the problem and I had to identify the user running the command from the ruby script. If you have any alternate ways of doing this plz let me know but you've nailed the problem down.

Comment: Done. I've given you some ideas too. We take a different approach to you, using different tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that in order to connect to the X session, the user must have permission to do so (via Xauthority, likely).  The www-data user that the web server is running as does not have such permission.

If you are trying to do things with an X environment in the context of a web request (especially launching a web browser, as it appears you are doing), then you should probably re-think your approach, as this sounds like a bad idea.

We (at [Flippa.com](https://flippa.com/)) have to open web pages for various reasons, due to the nature of what we do.  We use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), which also requires an X server, though we run a headless X server called [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), via the [Headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) gem.  We don't do such things in the context of a web request, however, as that is typically an expensive process.  We run a bunch of Resque workers in the background and off-load that work to be executed asynchronously.  Perhaps you should consider an approach like that.

Also, if you're launching Firefox in order to scrape web content, take screenshots etc, you may want to look at phantomjs, which is intended to be used programatically, rather than on the desktop.

Here's an example of a current screenshot we took using phantomjs.

https://flippa.com/auctions/2703649/screenshots/30b037b026044f58764888995d41c020.png

Comment: Thanks again. PhantomJS was my first attempt at taking snapshots, the problem was that it did not render flash elements and the issue wasn't well documented. These are some great ideas, I will give them a try.

Comment: On a side note, move to PhantomJS 1.5 which is pure headless on Linux. No more X or Xvfb needed.

Comment: @AriyaHidayat, wow, really? That is excellent news :)  We'll try it out.

Comment: Get subscribed to the mailing-list to always obtain the fresh and future updates!